# PHP check load time left after submision

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add a progress bar that shows the percentage as in the "preparing the next page" before redirect.

I got the progress bar animation going, but now I need to know an estimate of how long it will take before it redirects.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xyatddy0/1/

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
      $('#pb div').stop(true).animate({ width: $(this).attr('class') + '%'}, 
                                      { step: function(now) { $(this).text(Math.round(now) + '%');},
            duration: 1000
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="progressbar" id="pb"><div>0%</div></div>
<a href="#" class="0">Set 0%</a>
<a href="#" class="20">Set 20%</a>
<a href="#" class="40">Set 40%</a>
<a href="#" class="100">Set 100%</a>
```

Somewhat like this: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html but for a page redirect

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are looking for is dependent on external factors outside of your control, so you won't be able to accomplish your stated goal. That's just how the internet works - different people will have different load times depending on the routes to your server, and those routes change in real time, every second of every day based on what the routers determine is most optimal at that time. Various other factors come into play as well (e.g. are you loading content from third party servers - that's another variable that you can't control, etc.)

Comment: I see what you mean. So the most user friendly way to let the user know what's happening is show a spinning bar or something like that

Comment: Yes - an indicator that shows progress is being made is as good as you can get; you make that go away once your code indicates the page load is complete. You just can't show an estimate of how much time is left.